# Twitter cannot resolve the address

Tags: dns, azure, google-cloud-platform, twitter

There is a website which is distributed via Azure CDN. The CDN endpoint was used as a destination of CNAME entry for `www.< EXAMPLE >.com` with usage of Google DNS. The www address to the website works fine with one exception, twitter cannot resolve the address `https://www.<EXAMPLE>.io`, thereby it cannot read meta tags to generate so called *[twitter card](https://images.app.goo.gl/MXEsTK2qpDa8JN3o9)*. On [the twitter validator page](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) when you try validate above address it will return following message:

*ERROR: Fetching the page failed because the fetcher cannot resolve the address.*

However, when you enter CDN endpoint address (`https://EXAMPLE.azureedge.net`) in the same validator  then everything is fine and Twitter is able to read the website content. Also [facebook sharing debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) doesn't complain.

Below you can see obscure `dig` output for `www.EXAMPLE.io` domain.

```
www.EXAMPLE.io.     60                      IN CNAME    EXAMPLE.azureedge.net.
EXAMPLE.azureedge.net. 1799                 IN CNAME    EXAMPLE.afd.azureedge.net.
EXAMPLE.afd.azureedge.net. 299              IN CNAME    afd.t-XXXX.t-msedge.net.
afd.t-XXXX.t-msedge.net. 200                IN CNAME    t-XXXX.t-msedge.net.
t-XXXX.t-msedge.net.    43                  IN CNAME    XXXXXXXXXXXXX.ctrl.t-XXXX.t-msedge.net.
XXXXXXXXXXXXX.ctrl.t-XXXX.t-msedge.net. 223 IN CNAME    standard.t-XXXX.t-msedge.net.
standard.t-XXXX.t-msedge.net. 236           IN A        1.2.3.4
```

What can cause the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are other sites able to resolve the address properly? How long has this been happening? Is this a brand new domain? Have you given time for whatever nameservers Twitter uses to refresh their DNS? If this is a problem specific to twitter then this may be better at [webapps.se], for it to be on topic here you would have to show it was not *just* a Twitter problem as website and webapp problems are off topic here except insofar as the problem is in connecting with your computer or computers.

Comment: Hi @Mokubai, (1) as I mentioned facebook sharing debugger doesn't have a problem with resolving domain. (2) It's happening from the beginning (3) The domain is old, previously pointing to an old site (old provider), it was updated  recently to the new site (CDN). (4) The site is up and running for 2 weeks now (1 Feb), so yes I believe there was enough time for Twitter to refresh their DNS. OK I'll ask then on `Web Applications` then. Thanks